# CodeIgniter incorrect URL when submitting form

Tags: forms, codeigniter, submit

I just started using CodeIgniter today, and was following the tutorial at [the CI website](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html).

When I got to the final step for creating a new news item, I ran into an issue with the form submit. I would expect the URL to be `jonhopkins.net/news/create` when I press the form's submit button, but it is going to `http://jonhopkins.net/news/jonhopkins.net/news/create` instead, which is clearly very wrong, and I have no idea why this is happening. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Everything else on my site (the Pages part of the tutorial) works perfectly. This is the only thing that is breaking. All of my code is exactly as it appears in the tutorial, except for a change to what happens when an item is successfully submitted to the database, which currently is never happening.

**News Controller**

```
public function create() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $data['title'] = 'Create a news item';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'text', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        //$success will contain the slug of the created item, or FALSE if database insertion failed
        $success = $this->news_model->set_news();
        if ($success) {
            $this->_doView($success);
        } else {
            echo "Something went wrong while trying to submit the news item.";
        }
    }
}

public function view($slug) {
    $this->_doView($slug);
}

private function _doView($slug) {
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);
    if (empty($data['news_item'])) {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Create View**

```
<h2>Create a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('news/create') ?>
    <label for="title">Title</label> 
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 
</form>
```

And the resulting HTML...

```
<form action="jonhopkins.net/news/create" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
    <label for="title">Title</label> 
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" /> 
</form>
```

**News Model** I don't think it's ever getting here, but just in case

```
public function set_news() {
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $slug,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
        'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    );

    if ($this->db->insert('news', $data)) {
        return $slug;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `form_open('news/create')` method uses the `$CI->Config->site_url()` method which, in turn, uses the `base_url` from your config file.

Make sure your `$config['base_url']` is set to your domain (with trailing slash) in the `application/config/config.php` file.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://jonhopkins.net/';
```

Comment: Wow.. You have got to be kidding. I had it as `$config['base_url'] = 'jonhopkins.net'` without the `http://`. I added that, and now it works... I never thought that would make a difference. But thank you so much.